# to check if a line before and after a string empty

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I need to delete certain numbers of line before a desired text but only if a line before and after searched string is empty.

E.g (line number, content)

```
1    
2
3 Hello
4
5 yellow
```

in this case, if lines before and after line containing Hello are empty (line 2 and 4), i have to delete lines from 3 to 1.

I can delete lines from 3 to 1 using tac and sed command but m having difficulty in putting tht if condition.

```
tac file1|sed -e '/Hello/,+3d'|tac
```

Comment: Do you have to use `sed`? This would be easier to do with `awk`.

Comment: Do you have `GNU sed 4.4` ? The new option `-z` can help.

Comment: @WalterA How does `-z` help with this?

Comment: `sed '1 N;N;N;N;{s/\n\nHello\n\n/\n/}' file` might work (if you have a GNU sed).

Comment: Use awk's "paragraph" mode by setting `RS` to an empty string. It will then treat a block of lines with blank lines around them as records.

Comment: @Barmar; I posted an answer using `-z`.

Comment: Can the `Hello` line appear multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following if you are ok with `awk`.

```
awk -v string="Hello" '
FNR==NR{
  a[FNR]=$0
  next
}
($0==string) && a[FNR-1]=="" && a[FNR+1]==""{
  a[FNR-1]=a[FNR]=a[FNR-2]="del_flag"
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++){
    if(a[i]!="del_flag"){
      print a[i]
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

Comment: With an input file like `printf "%s\n" "one" "two" "" "Hello" "" "Hello" "" "yellow"` (two lines with `hello` and an overlapping empty line) both `Hello`'s are deleted. The specs are unclear, maybe better, maybe worse than the two `sed`  solutions.

Comment: @WalterA, I considered samples from OP and created this, I am in cab as of now so couldn't test your provided sample, will check it once in home but not sure of OP's Input_file is same or not.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed ':a;N;s/\n/&/3;Ta;/\n\n.*Hello.*\n$/s/.*\n//;ta;P;D' file
```

Gather up 4 lines in the pattern space and if the 2nd and the 4th are empty and the 3rd contains `Hello`, delete the first three lines and repeat. Otherwise print the first line and repeat.

Comment: `:a;ta;` - is that `t a` doing there something? This looks almost like endless loop.

Comment: @KamilCuk Ah! It's a bit of cruft left over from my testing. BTW it just resets the `t` flag set to true when a substitution has taken place. I noticed that when using the `D` command the flag is not reset at the beginning of cycle and so apply belt and braces when using them before testing. In this case the `ta` command resets the flag anyway and allows the remaining line in the pattern space to be included in the next cycle.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed` option `-z` you can match

```
some_line
empty line
line With Hello
empty line
```

and replace this with an empty line.

```
sed -rz 's/(^|\n)[^\n]*\n\nHello\n\n/\1\n/g' file1
```

EDIT: added `g` for multiple segments.

Comment: The documentation I found says that `-z` is for using a null byte as the line separator, instead of newline. It has nothing to do with empty lines.

Comment: @Barmar With `-z` you can match 2 empty lines with  `(^|\n)\n\n`. Without `-z` `sed` is line oriented  (match one empty line with `^$`, and you need advanced @potong magic for two empty lines in a row).

Comment: I see, you're just treating the entire input as a single line, since there's no null byte anywhere. Don't you need the `g` modifier to match multiple times?